# Debug.Print Item of 2D Collection

Tags: excel, vba, collections

I finally managed to populate a Collection with two variables per entry. I do so by defining a Class Module called "DataRange", which looks like this:

```
Public Strain As Double
Public Stress As Double
```

This is how I populate my Collection:

```
Sub ECalc()

Dim j As Integer
Dim mycol As Collection
Dim c As DataRange

Set mycol = New Collection
Set c = New DataRange

For j = 1 To 200
    c.Strain = Sheets("Data").Range("I" & j).Value2
    c.Stress = Sheets("Data").Range("K" & j).Value2
    mycol.Add c
Next j
Debug.Print mycol.Count ' <--- This does work, I can see how many entries have been created (200 as stated by j = 200)
Debug.Print mycol.Item(20) ' <--- This does not work. WHY?
End Sub
```

The code does populate my collection as I get a number of entries by "mycol.Count". However, I cannot access a single Item as in the last line of the code. An error comes up stating: "Runtime Error 438 object doesn't support this property or method"

What am I doing wrong?

Extra Info: I do not want to use Arrays as I plan to resize the collection in subsequent steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit** to enlarge the answer to an issue I found in OP's code

it's because with

```
mycol.Item(20)
```

you're referencing an `object` (an object of class `DataRange`) which has not a "default" value

so you have to code:

```
Debug.Print mycol.Item(20).Stress ' print the 'Stress' property of the 'DataRange' object stored as the 20th item of your collection 
Debug.Print mycol.Item(21).Strain ' print the 'Strain' property of the 'DataRange' object stored as the 21th item of your collection
```

But you have to move `Set c = New DataRange` statement inside the `For` loop, as follows:

```
Sub ECalc()

    Dim j As Long
    Dim mycol As Collection
    Dim c As DataRange

    Set mycol = New Collection

    For j = 1 To 200
        Set c = New DataRange ' instantiate a new object of type 'DataRange' at every iteration
        c.Strain = Sheets("Data").Range("I" & j).Value2 'assign current object 'Strain' property
        c.Stress = Sheets("Data").Range("K" & j).Value2 'assign current object 'Stress' property
        mycol.Add c ' add current object to the collection
    Next

End Sub
```

otherwise ALL collection items would reference the SAME `DataRange` object you instantiate before the `For` loop, thus leaving you with all of them with the SAME `Strain` and `Stress` property read from the last "Data" sheet row in columns I and K